# Alertify.alert not closing on button click

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic and Cordova to build an app and the alertify message appears fine but does not close when I click ok. I have tried to add onocclick functions to try and solve the issue but this done nothing.
Here is my code:

```
    if (($scope.loginData.username==undefined)&&($scope.loginData.password==undefined)){
        alertify.alert("You have not entered a username and a password.");
        return;
    }

    else if ($scope.loginData.username==undefined){
        alertify.alert("You have not entered a username.").set('label', 'Ok');
        return;
    }

    else if ($scope.loginData.password==undefined){
        alertify.alert("You have not entered a password.");
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing the onok method

```
'onok': function(){ alertify.success('Great');}
```

Consider checking out this template for the alert

```
var closable = alertify.alert().setting('closable');

alertify.alert()
  .setting({
    'label':'Agree',
    'message': 'This dialog is : ' + (closable ? ' ' : ' not ') + 'closable.' ,
    'onok': function(){ alertify.success('Great');}
  }).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this problem in 2018, I encountered it twice on ios and i resolved both scenarios by removing one of the css packages/libraries in the project.

Apparently, there are some styles from bootstrap that affects the functionality of Alertify (in my own case).

You might want to check out all the other libraries with styles and CSS files in your project.